# Switch on ESP8266

Tags: switches, esp8266

I'm not that good in electronics, so maybe what I'll write bellow might sound awkward to you. If so, please correct me where needed, or ask me for any other more details.

I'm trying to add a standard wall switch to an [ESP8266](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2471/0A-ESP8266__Datasheet__EN_v4.3.pdf) [module](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/048/352/original/adafruit_products_schem.png?1511209629). I've set as input for the switch 3v from the ESP module, and for output I've used: a 10k resistor connected with the - of esp, to clear the residual current; and also connected on an input pin of the ESP module. This seems to be working fine, but from time to time I get some signals like the switch was turned on/off, without anybody using it.
Is there another way to achieve this? Thank you!

Edit: I've added the schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcTlem.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Add a schematic please, edit your question and press `Ctrl + M` to open the embedded schematic editor.

Comment: K, will try do create one. Than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help if the false operation is happening only when the switch is open. Disable the internal pullup/down resistor and don't use one of the GPIO pins that determines bootup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUn7UT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 1K supplies only 3.3mA which is not really sufficient voltage or current for reliable operation of a mains wall switch, I'm afraid, but you may get away with it.

A proper design might use a 12-24V supply, perhaps 20mA, and reduce the voltage down to go into the MCU, with some transient suppression as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The mains switch is only used on the esp module, which uses a relay for the 220v lights. I'll add a schematic when I'll get home

Comment: @Piter Yes, that is exactly what I have assumed from your description. Mechanical switches don't like current/voltage that is too high **or** too low.

Comment: Hi! I've added a schematic, maybe you can check it and see if it makes more sense?

Comment: No change to my answer - it's inverted compared to yours but that's a simple change in your firmware.

Comment: So the issue is with the mains switch, that ... is unreliable at low voltage? And having the 10k resistor is helping, meaning I see the result when the switch is pressed, but sometimes it gets automatically triggered on and off, for a fraction of a second - I was thinking to update the sw on ESP module to "ignore" this case.

Comment: Maybe maybe not. If the issue happens only when the switch is closed that may be the case. If the issue happens when the switch is open then it's probably EMI pickup on the wires to the switch (more likely IMO). You can try to filter with software checking multiple times a few ms apart. Or use the RC filter shown above, which also puts some series Z on the ground (or 3.3V in your case) which can prevent some other potential issues. If it happens with switch open or closed then it's not the  switch wetting current, it's probably EMI getting in somewhere else.

Comment: Hi! Yes, it happens only when the switch is closed... kind of fixed it by software, the hardware way to fix it seems too difficult ... at least to me :( Thank you for your help!!